# How we get Spinner Id not Selected item?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I want to get th id of spinner dynamically created.I dont want to get the id of selected item.
I want to get spinner owns id on item selection.
My code is..

```
  private OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        }
```

Comment: Try this : yourSpinner.getId();

Comment: You can use the `View arg1`. `arg1.getId()`should return the id of the spinner. If it does not, just use the id of the parent.

Comment: @Haresh i dont know the name off spinner, i created dynamically.
I want to get id on listener.

Comment: @Pphoenix it not work

Comment: @Pphoenix how we get tag of dynamically created spinner?

Comment: @Nadeem did you set an id when you created it dynamically? If you didn't then there is no id to get.

Answer (score 0):

if you add View dynamically then it haven't id.id generate for make relation between xml widget and java  you can set tag for your spinner and then getTag.

Comment: how we get tag of dynamically created spinner?

Comment: when you create it set spinner.setTag(uniqueNumber) and when ever you want you can call spinner.getTag()